# Providing metadata to the visual designer in VB.Net to align user controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, alignment, visualdesigner

I'm creating a UserControl in Vb.Net. It consists of a TextBox and a button containing an ellipsis. When moving a normal TextBox around the visual designer, it is possible to align the TextBox with other controls. BUT, it is also possible to align the base of the text in the TextBox with the base of the text in other controls.

What propert(ies) do I expose in my UserControl to be able to do this in the visual designer?

Many thanks,

Mark

Comment: There is no property to expose in the UserControl.  This is design feature exposed by the [ControlDesigner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner(v=vs.110).aspx) `SnapLines` property.  You will need to create a custom designer and then decorate the UserControl with a [DesignerAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to tell the design environment to use your custom designer.  This is not a trivial task.

Comment: In that case, I probably won't investigate further as it's so far down the list. Many thanks for your help.